# Get the children tag from an array of objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I'm trying to get the children img from an array which is populated with objects.

Here is the console for the array:

```
["<div class="showcase-content">                
<img src="…5/multimedia/1_1/1.jpg" alt="02">        
</div>", 
"<div class="showcase-content">             
<i…365/multimedia/1_1/2.jpg" alt="02">      
</div>", 
"<div class="showcase-content">             
<img src="…dia/1_1/3.jpg" alt="02">         
</div>", 
"<div class="showcase-content">             
<img src="h…ia/1_1/4.jpg" alt="02">         
</div>"]
```

So, I just used `console.log(contentArray);` but, if I try `console.log(contentArray[0].children('img').src);` it says its undefined.

**Question:**
How can I reach img tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap the `html` in jQuery.

```
$(contentArray[0]).children('img').attr('src')
```

Comment: 1 more thing @Tushar ... is there a way to get the width of the img too?

Comment: @OzZie Not until you throw it in `DOM`

Answer (score 0):

May be, this works? Try this in jQuery:

```
$(contentArray).first().children('img').attr('src');
```

This gets the `contentArray`'s first element's image child and gets the `src`!